# Inline lambda function creation behaviour in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

If I have a method like this

```
void SomeMethod () {
    Func<A,B> f =  a => /*Some code*/;
    ...
    b = f (a);
}
```

is `f` created every time `SomeMethod` is called? I mean, does that line take time to compute or does the compiler store the function somewhere on compile time skips it at execution?

Comment: A Func is an object and the body is "stored" in the same way a normal method is (so it is not "recomputed"). Or is this a question about if `f`, on subsequent invocations of SomeMethod, will be "reference equals"? (I believe it will be, but do not have a reference off-hand.)

Comment: @user2864740 If you compare the `f` of one call with the `f` from a later call, they will be different as references and instances, so `ReferenceEquals` will be false, but they will be equal according to the [relevant override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ts3c5tx.aspx) of `Equals`. The last fact is required by the C# Specification. Also note that `operator ==` [is overloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5wz9hhy.aspx) here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this simple example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Test();
     Test();
}
static void Test()
{
     Func<int, int> f = a => a * a;
     int b = f(2);
     Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

The created method is:

[image]

And the IL code for `<Test>b__0`:

```
.method private hidebysig static int32  '<Test>b__0'(int32 a) cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] int32 CS$1$0000)
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  mul
  IL_0003:  stloc.0
  IL_0004:  br.s       IL_0006
  IL_0006:  ldloc.0
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method Program::'<Test>b__0'
```

IL code for `Test` method:

```
    .method private hidebysig static void  Test() cil managed
{
  // Code size       49 (0x31)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,int32> f,
           [1] int32 b)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldsfld     class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,int32> ConsoleApplication10.Program::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1'
  IL_0006:  brtrue.s   IL_001b
  IL_0008:  ldnull
  IL_0009:  ldftn      int32 ConsoleApplication10.Program::'<Test>b__0'(int32)
  IL_000f:  newobj     instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,int32>::.ctor(object,
                                                                                       native int)
  IL_0014:  stsfld     class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,int32> ConsoleApplication10.Program::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1'
  IL_0019:  br.s       IL_001b
  IL_001b:  ldsfld     class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,int32> ConsoleApplication10.Program::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1'
  IL_0020:  stloc.0
  IL_0021:  ldloc.0
  IL_0022:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0023:  callvirt   instance !1 class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<int32,int32>::Invoke(!0)
  IL_0028:  stloc.1
  IL_0029:  ldloc.1
  IL_002a:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_002f:  nop
  IL_0030:  ret
} // end of method Program::Test
```

Every time you call `Test` method, the  the cached anonymous delegate (which is `Func<int,int>`) is loaded, then the `Invoke` method is called.

So the answer is, anonymous method (`<Test>b__0`) is created only once by the compiler, it's not created every time you call the function.

Comment: Exactly, the static method `'<Test>b__0'` from the IL is what I called `StrangeName` in my answer.

Comment: If some variables are trapped by closure, how does the compiler deal with this?

Answer (score 4):

The C# compiler creates an ordinary (non-anonymous) method from the lambda arrow, then the delegate `f` will have that "generated" method on its invocation list.

Each time the `SomeMethod` runs, a new instance of `Func<,>` delegate is created which refers the ordinary (but generated) method.

It is just like:

```
void SomeMethod () {
    Func<A, B> f = StrangeName;
    ...
    b = f(a);
}

static B StrangeName(A a) {
    /*Some code*/
}
```

Comment: If some variables are trapped by closure, how does the compiler deal with this?

Comment: @CristianGarcia Excellent comment. If those variables are fields, they will be accessed by `\*Some code*/`. Maybe some instance references will need to be passed to `StrangeName`, or `StrangeName` might be made non-static. If those variables are local variables, they will be promoted to fields by the compiler, either fields in the same class or fields in a new generated class, let's call it `StrangeNameClass`. The details depend on just what variables are "trapped", and on implementation choices by the C# compiler authors.